# List Validation with IF & LEN

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, formula, list-validation

SharePoint Guru's please guide me to complete List request.

**Requirements**: I have been creating a List for doing User Audit

- Manager has to select the Choice either Approved or Rejected under Access Retain column
- Whenever Manager selects the Rejected option he/she has to fill the Ticket details on another column (Ticket for Approval) as mandatory but not for Approved choice
- I am able to achieve the same using this formula: `=IF([Access Retain]="Rejected",IF([Ticket for Removal]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)`
- Issue comes when we try to the validate the Ticket column which should be 15 char(TKTxxx).
- I tried **LEN** Function with different syntax with above formula, none is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula, it should work for you:

```
=IF(LEN([Ticket column])=15,IF([Access Retain]="Rejected",IF([Ticket for Removal]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE),FALSE)
```

**Documentation**: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

---

**Update from comments**:

Final working formula is:

```
=IF([Access Retain]="Rejected",IF(AND([Ticket for Removal]<>"",LEN([Ticket for Removal])=15,LEFT([Ticket for Removal],3)="TKT",TRUE),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, Formula is worked as expected but now Approved choice is also asking details on [Ticket for Removal] column, hence tried below formula  '=OR(IF(LEN([Ticket for Removal])=0,IF([Access Retain]="Approved",IF([Ticket for Removal]<>"",TRUE,TRUE),FALSE),FALSE
,IF(LEN([Ticket for Removal])=15,IF([Access Retain]="Rejected",IF([Ticket for Removal]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE),FALSE))'  -- Now issue with column is not allowing a Empty field, which is default when we initial ask manger to do audit

Comment: Is it working for you completely or not? Is [Ticket column] length also dependent on `[Access Retain]="Rejected"` condition?

Comment: Yep, Condition is working, but its' also seeking 15 Char for approval choice too.

Comment: Try using this formula & let me know if it works: `=IF([Access Retain]="Rejected",IF(AND([Ticket for Removal]<>"",LEN([Ticket for Removal])=15),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)`.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the `[Ticket for Removal]` value to be exactly 15 characters?

Comment: yep, want to fix with 15 char Exactly, last formula is working but allowing to save less than 15 char too. later have to check content on column start with TKT followed by 12 n#.

Comment: Does this allow less than 15 characters in case of [Access Retain] is equal to "Rejected"? Can you specify all your conditions related to Approved/Rejected values & column length in your question?

Comment: Firstly want to Thank you for helping me with queries :) .  REQ : - User will be given 2 Choice to be selected under Access Retain Column - Approved or Rejected. --- IF Approved is selected the next Column Ticket for Removal can be Empty ---- But when Rejected is selected Next Ticket column should having details of Ticket eg. TKT000003397492(15char) fixed content starting with TKTxxx -- user should not be allowed to key-in some chunk char & Save the list

Comment: For first two conditions: Ticket for Removal column should not be empty & it should have exactly 15 characters (when [Access Retain] is equal to "Rejected"), this formula should work: `=IF([Access Retain]="Rejected",IF(AND([Ticket for Removal]<>"",LEN([Ticket for Removal])=15),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)`.

Comment: Done with Request -- Thank you for supporting --- Final Formula `=IF([Access Retain]="Rejected",IF(AND([Ticket for Removal]<>"",LEN([Ticket for Removal])=15,LEFT([Ticket for Removal],3)="TKT",TRUE),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)`

Comment: Great, glad it is working for you now!